# After Insalling Ubuntu 16.04 Grub couldn't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I'm a computer Engineering student. I decided to try Ubuntu. During the installation, I checked the button that **Removes All Disk and Install Ubuntu**. After due time, I got the message saying that installation is done and I should restart. When I restarted, there was a black screen with a message:

```
Checking Media Presence.....  
No Media Present....
```

I'm writing this on Live USB.

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: How exactly did you install Ubuntu? In the mean time I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate (see above).

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht where did you get that last line of your edit from?

Comment: @muru The one which you removed? It was in the original question. :)

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht ah, it was in the quote block. I thought you got it from a comment.

Comment: @muru Ohk. Apologies. But I thought that it should not be a part of the quote block (which included the message from the system) because it was something that the user had done. You got it. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your BIOS is trying to boot from the USB alone ; did you update the boot options of your BIOS so it can boot on your HDD you installed Ubuntu on ?
If not, go to BIOS setup on computer startup, then boot options, and bring your HDD up the list so it can be booted from.